# Java REST service - Unable to open resource url

Tags: java, rest, web-services, google-chrome, jersey-2.0

Initially i have developed web scraping using chrome to scrape the data from the required websites,so now i want to convert in this java application into REST service,
so below is my code , while executing received "`unable to open resource url make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running`"

```
 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain")
 public String getText() throws InterruptedException {
         WebDriver driver;
         File file = new File("resources/chromedriver.exe");
         String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", absolutePath);
         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");

                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,
                            timeoutInSeconds);
                    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Object>) new ExpectedCondition<Object>() {

                        @Override
                        public Object apply(@Nullable WebDriver input) {
                            WebElement divProgress = input.findElement(By
                                    .id("phasesTableContainer"));
                            return divProgress;
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                    String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='price']")).getText();
return price;
```

received "`unable to open resource url make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running`

from server (glass fish) -

```
Info:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.fee.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.fee.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:33)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:335)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at com.usfee.MyPathResource.getText(MyPathResource.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Note: i'm new to this (REST service), please guide me 
Problem in the below line

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Can you show some of the scraping code? Your project isn't deploying because of the NoSuchMethodError exception, and the error messages suggest it's MyPathResource doesn't have a method called getText

Comment: @JordanMackie : Thanks , the above code are available in getText method, with return type String " without any scraping code just return some text its working perfectly

Comment: I'm fairly sure your error isn't coming from the code you've given us. Can you show ApplicationConfig?

Comment: @JordanMackie : Thanks, added my complete method

Comment: Awesome! Include a check that  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='price']")) isnt null and see what that says.

Comment: Just so you know, your REST implementation looks fine! Your error is due an error when your ChromeDriver is trying to parse the website.